# Inital Data Load Unauthenticated Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

So I have an iOS app that is using Firebase as a backend service.  When my app initially launches (before the user signs up) I want to pull a list of all the "Schools" available to use.

/Schools is the path where all the schools will be.

```
{
 "rules": {
   ".read": "auth != null",
   ".write": "auth != null",
  }
}
```

Currently I only have default rules in place.  What rules should I apply so that an unauthenticated user can read from /Schools and not .write?

I'd also like to keep the default rules in place as well for the rest of the database except on /schools

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your rules look like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": false,
    "Schools": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": false,
    }
  }
}
```

With this, everything under the "/Schools" location will be readable by everyone, but not writable.